# Jenkins windows 10 local Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

Tags: java, jenkins, windows-10, port

After doing a fresh installation of Jenkins version 2.202 and an installation of the latest jdk 1.8.0 on Windows 10 Pro, I kept on receiving the same error: Bad Reqest - Invalid hostname.

I tried to run the following java command from cmd: java -jar jenkins.war

I got the following error:

```
Running from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
2019-11-04 17:36:31.259+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @541ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2019-11-04 17:36:31.344+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2019-11-04 17:36:31.364+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath
2019-11-04 17:36:31.401+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT; built: 2019-05-02T00:04:53.875Z; git: e1bc35120a6617ee3df052294e433f3a25ce7097; jvm 1.8.0_231-b11
2019-11-04 17:36:31.796+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2019-11-04 17:36:31.833+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2019-11-04 17:36:31.833+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2019-11-04 17:36:31.836+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#startScavenging: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2019-11-04 17:36:32.102+0000 [id=1]     INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\alainghawi\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
2019-11-04 17:36:32.169+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@5efa40fe{Jenkins v2.202,/,file:///C:/Users/alainghawi/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Users\alainghawi\.jenkins\war}
2019-11-04 17:36:32.176+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStop: Stopped ServerConnector@5ebec15{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-11-04 17:36:32.176+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.session.HouseKeeper#stopScavenging: node0 Stopped scavenging
2019-11-04 17:36:32.179+0000 [id=1]     INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextDestroyed: Shutting down a Jenkins instance that was still starting up
java.lang.Throwable: reason
        at hudson.WebAppMain.contextDestroyed(WebAppMain.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ContextHandler.java:965)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextDestroyed(ServletContextHandler.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.stopContext(ContextHandler.java:942)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.stopContext(ServletContextHandler.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1503)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.stopContext(WebAppContext.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:1009)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
        at winstone.Launcher.shutdown(Launcher.java:313)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:200)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:362)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
Exception in thread "Jenkins initialization thread" 2019-11-04 17:36:32.189+0000 [id=1] INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStop: Stopped w.@5efa40fe{Jenkins v2.202,/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Users\alainghawi\.jenkins\war}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/util/HudsonFailedToLoad
        at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:555)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
2019-11-04 17:36:32.191+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Jetty shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:189)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:362)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:396)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:187)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
        ... 14 more
2019-11-04 17:36:32.211+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:308)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:396)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:187)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:189)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:362)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
```

However, when I run netstat -ano | find "8080", I only find the System pid which is 4 listening to the port 8080, and I can't kill it as it is the sytem process. What should I do to make Jenkins work on my Windows 10 local machine?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may try running Jenkins on different port, e.g 8081.`java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081`

Comment: I tried on different ports. It only worked on a port that no one is listening to. But if I remember correctly, in older versions of Java you could run it on a port and bind it.